# How to change the format of the dates and compare it

Tags: python, datetime

I have got two variable as

```
x = 27.01.2022 
y= 12.06.2022
```

I want to compare two dates and want to print true if y > x else print false. I am doing this:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(27.01.2022)
y = datetime.datetime(12.06.2022)

if x>y:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

```
File "<string>", line 3
    x = datetime.datetime(27.01.2022)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Periods should be commas? And the parameter order is not DD MM YYYY

Comment: You got a syntax error because `27.01.2022` is neither a string (they must be enclosed in quotes), nor a number (because of the two dots), nor anything else Python can understand.
A correct equivalent call would be: `datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 27)`.

Comment: @ Luc125 Thank you. I have edited the question. I have got the dates as output from above nested dictionary as I need to compare the dates. As the output dates has dot in it then how to compare the dates. Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your code blocks are valid syntax. Please refer [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) on examples of using datetime instances

You don't have a time, so you really only need date objects. And you can print a boolean result directly

```
from datetime import date
x = date.fromisoformat('2022-01-27')
y = date.fromisoformat('2022-06-12')
print(x > y)
```

Comment: I have edited the question. I have got the dates as output from above nested dictionary and then I need to compare the dates. As the output dates has dot in it then how to compare the dates. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: I answered your question, as it was originally written. Please accept it, then create a new question with your actual code you're having a problem with

Comment: Sure. No problem.